# How to OrderBy difference between two dates that are nullable with proper translation to SQL?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have dictionary

```
var OrderBy = new Dictionary<string, IQueryable<Something>>
{
    (...)

    { "DateDifference", OrderDirection == "asc" ?
                        query.OrderBy(x => x.Date1.Value.Date - x.Date2.Value.Date) :
                        query.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date1.Value.Date - x.Date2.Date)},
};
```

But there'll be exception when it'll try to evaluate that on `Something` which has any of those Dates equal to null

Anybody has an idea how to do it?

Comment: Does `x.Date1?.Value.Date - x.Date2?.Value.Date` work?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen ``An expression tree lambda may not contain a null propagating operator. ``

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I probably managed to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I'm a hacker

```
var OrderBy = new Dictionary<string, IQueryable<Something>>
{
    (...)

    { "DateDifference", input.OrderDirection == "asc" 

                        ?

                        input.OrderBy(x => 
                        (x.Date1 == null ? new DateTime(0).Date : x.Date1.Value.Date)
                        -
                        (x.Date2 == null ? new DateTime(0).Date : x.Date2.Value.Date)) 

                        :

                        input.OrderByDescending(x => 
                        (x.Date1 == null ? new DateTime(0).Date : x.Date1.Value.Date)
                        -
                        (x.Date2 == null ? new DateTime(0).Date : x.Date2.Value.Date)) },
};
```